# Cube root of a fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner with cube roots.

My textbook says:

$$
x = \sqrt[3]{\frac {2}{3}}= -1 = \sqrt[3]{-1}
$$

I'm not sure how the author got this answer. Could somebody show the steps?

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain that is what the textbook says? Because the cube root of two thirds most definitely does not equal a negative number.

Comment: In the field with five elements, the cube root of $2\cdot 3^{-1}$ is $-1$.

Comment: This is almost certainly not what the author meant, by the way.

Comment: Ha, but I figured the fellow didn't mean his question in some sort of group theory or abstract algebra context.

Comment: It says $x=\sqrt[3]{\frac23}$ **or** $x=\sqrt[3]{-1}$, not that $x$ equals both at the same time.

Comment: The source is Mary Jane Sterling, [*U Can: Algebra I for dummies*, p. 307](https://books.google.com/books?id=_PQbCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA307&ots=JHUEGoiktO&dq=%22divide%20the%20first%20equation%20through%20by%203%22&pg=PA307#v=onepage&q=%22divide%20the%20first%20equation%20through%20by%203%22&f=false).

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm new with MathJax too. I've added screenshots from the book to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, the author somewhat badly formatted his/her textbook so it confused you. The author is not saying that $\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}} = -1$, he/she is just placing the corresponding solutions to two *different* equations side by side.

Equation 1 is $x^3 = -1$ with solution $\sqrt[3]{-1} = -1$.

Equation 2 is $x^3 = \frac{2}{3}$ with solution $ \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}$.

**Edit**: With this taken in context with the second image you uploaded, the author is demonstrating how you can find the real roots (zeros, solutions) of $2x^{-6}-x^{-3}-3=0$ by factoring it into $(2x^{-3}-3)(x^3+1)=0$, then treating each factor as a seperate equation for which to solve for $x$, thus yielding $-1$ and $\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}$ as your solutions to the original bigger equation.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I misunderstood that she was indicating two solutions (I should have understood that from the context though), not simplifying or rewriting one.

Answer (score 2):

The question concerns an equation $$2x^{-6} - x^{-3} -3 = 0$$

which the book factors to $$(2x^{-3}-3)(x^{-3}+1) = 0$$ using the technique of substituting $q=x^{-3}$ to make the equation look simpler.

Since we now have the product of two numbers, and the product is 0, at least one of the two numbers must be 0.  In particular, we must have $2x^{-3}-3 = 0 \color{red}{\text{ or }} x^{-3}+1 = 0$.  (Or conceivably both.)

If $x^{-3}+1 = 0$ then, multiplying both sides by $x^3$: $$\begin{align}
1 + x^3 & = 0 \\
x^3 & = -1\\
x & = \sqrt[3]{-1}
\end{align}$$

In the other case, that $2x^{-3}-3 = 0$, we do the same thing, multiplying both sides by $x^3$:

$$\begin{align}
2 - 3x^3 & = 0 \\
3x^3 & = 2\\
x^3 & = \frac23\\
x & = \sqrt[3]{\frac23}
\end{align}$$

So in the end we have that $x = \sqrt[3]{-1} \color{red}{\text{ or }} x=\sqrt[3]{\frac23}$, and these are the answers.

If this isn't clear, please leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity here. I see the process exactly.